# Is there some system to convert 5.1 audio to binaural audio for headphones?

Tags: equipment, 5.1, binaural

I wish to plug something on my tv (optic output?) to listen 5.1 Netflix audio on headphones with binaural techniques.

Do you have some suggestion ? I would like to look for equipment options that make this trick.

Answer (score 0):

TC Electronic System 6000 has a program called Engage, in the 5.1 toolbox bank.

https://public.wsu.edu/~jkrug/Binaural-Test/

Comment: I would like to have equipment options to do it. Not software toolboxes.

Comment: The TC Electronic unit is a piece of digital hardware so not sure what you mean.